# fopen() gives permission denied error - despite chmod 777

Tags: php, fopen, file-permissions, lamp, fedora20

I get the following error on my Fedora 20 desktop running the LAMP stack when trying to use fopen()

> Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/php/documents/orders.txt):
>
> failed to open stream:
>
> Permission denied in /var/www/html/php/processorder.php on line 76

The code I used is

`$fp = fopen("$DOCUMENT_ROOT/php/documents/orders.txt", 'ab');`

*orders.txt* has the following permissions

> [root@localhost documents]# pwd
>
> /var/www/html/php/documents
>
> [root@localhost documents]# ls -l
>
> total 4
>
> -rwxrwxrwx. 1 byron web-content 12 Feb 21 12:33 orders.txt

I realise this question has been asked a number of times, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I am new to Linux/Fedora and to LAMP so I apologise if the error is borne out of ignorance.

Edit: Seems like SELinux was causing the problem, not sure how to overcome this in terms of changing settings in SELinux, so I disabled it.

To see whether SELinux is being enforced (I'm using Fedora 20) use */usr/sbin/sestatus*.

To disable SELinux, configure *SELINUX=disabled* in */etc/selinux/config*.

Comment: probably www user is not allowed to read some of those directories, solution is  `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www` where first www-data is user and second group

Comment: @kmlnvm : I have no user or group www-data, the user:group that owns all the files and directories recursively from /var/www (including www) is byron:web-content. I'm guessing the problem lies in httpd.conf, is this a possibility? Also, apache is a member of the group web-content.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like SELinux was causing the problem, not sure how to overcome this in terms of changing settings in SELinux, so I disabled it.

To see whether SELinux is being enforced (I'm using Fedora 20) use /usr/sbin/sestatus.

To disable SELinux, configure SELINUX=disabled in /etc/selinux/config.